# How to get a list of results in AQL based on another list?

Tags: sql

i know the title is unclear so let me explain my problem:

lets assume i have 2 tables :

- table "RESERVATION"

  `number`
- table "CUSTOMERS"

  `ID | reservationNum`

every customer can have multiple reservations.

given a list of customers ids i need to get a list of all the reservations that belong to them all

for example:

- customer 1 has reservations 100, 200 and 300
- customer 2 has reservations 100, 200, and 400
- customer 3 has reservations 100, 200, 300 and 600

the result will be {100,200}

how can it be done? what is the query i need to run ?

Comment: Worst way to write a question. Please rework on this

Comment: WHAT, needs to be done here? Do you have an actual complete table design, or are you expecting to get it here? Or do you need help with building the queries? Or both?

Comment: i wrote the table desin as is, and i need help with the query

Comment: The answer below should work for your case, but in all honesty such queries would be so much easier to achieve if you would have better table design. I.e. one table for reservations, one table for customers, one table for customerreservation relations, because right now your customers-table is not really a customers table, besides mixing pluralized and singularized table names ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure of your schema etc but essentially all you should need to do is count the number of times a reservation occurs in a set filtered by the customer ids and then check that the count is equal to the number of customers.

```
SELECT reservationNum
FROM Customers
WHERE Id IN (/* the list of customer ids */)
GROUP BY reservationNum
HAVING COUNT(1) = /* count of the list of customer ids */
```

Comment: I also provided a fiddle where this can be tested. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5466b9/25

Comment: thx for the answer! can you plz explain what is the meaning of HAVING COUNT(1) = XXX (in my example this is 2) ?

Comment: take a look at the last link I provided in the comment, in your case it should be 3, because there are 3 customers, i.e. the count of the reservationnumber itself inside the customers-table must equal the distinct count of customer ids, but there is no need to hardcode the number into the query